# Mongoose findOne() not returning a Promise

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

### Summary

I'm following this [course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/mern-stack-front-to-back/) with ends with completing this [app on github](https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector).

I'm getting stuck on the 10th lesson where I need to create a User Registration API and then test by making an AJAX POST request, when I try to make the `fetch` POST I get this error message.

[image]

When I try testing this with the **node debugger**, i.e. `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 server.js`

I see the code is not stopping in line 29 to execute the `.then` promise below.
[image]

This seems to indicate that `findOne()` is not returning a Promise as it should, even though I can see from the course I'm doing on Udemy that it is.  Also, the [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) says it returns a Promise too.

I've uploaded all the code to [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Holly845/devconnector) so that it is easier to reproduce.  But all the relevant code and logs are below too.

---

## Environment

- OSX 10.13.3
- node v8.11.1
- MongoDB shell version v4.0.1
- MongoDB server version v4.0.1

---

### LOGS

This is the output from the server console, there are no useful error messages after I make the fetch request...

```
in ~/devconnector
$ (master) npm run debug

> devconnector@1.0.0 debug /Users/holly/devconnector
> node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 server.js

Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/22164c98-654b-4056-9bae-9a8b8cf96ddf
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
(node:1892) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Server running on port 5000
MongoDB Connected
Debugger attached.
```

Here are the mongo DB logs, nothing is output after I make the fetch request on the frontend...

```
$ mongod
2018-09-09T12:12:03.431+0100 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1932 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=hollys-MacBook-Pro.local
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.1
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 54f1582fc6eb01de4d4c42f26fc133e623f065fb
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-09-09T12:12:03.445+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-09-09T12:12:03.446+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-09-09T12:12:03.446+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=7680M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-09-09T12:12:04.105+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1536491524:105407][1932:0x7fffa4bb1340], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 7/8320
2018-09-09T12:12:04.190+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1536491524:190433][1932:0x7fffa4bb1340], txn-recover: Recovering log 7 through 8
2018-09-09T12:12:04.247+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1536491524:247607][1932:0x7fffa4bb1340], txn-recover: Recovering log 8 through 8
2018-09-09T12:12:04.290+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1536491524:290380][1932:0x7fffa4bb1340], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2018-09-09T12:12:04.424+0100 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-09-09T12:12:04.593+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-09-09T12:12:04.750+0100 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2018-09-09T12:12:04.754+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2018-09-09T12:12:12.339+0100 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56872 #1 (1 connection now open)
2018-09-09T12:12:12.346+0100 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:56872 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.4" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "17.4.0" }, platform: "Node.js v8.11.1, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.3" }
```

---

### Here is my code...

**routes/api/users.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require("gravatar");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

// Load User model
const User = require("../../models/User");

// @route   GET api/users/test
// @desc    Tests users route
// @access  Public
router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "Users Works" }));

// @route   GET api/users/register
// @desc    Register user
// @access  Public
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  // function later(delay) {
  //   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
  //     setTimeout(resolve, delay);
  //   });
  // }
  // later(1000).then(() => {
  //   console.log("promise worked!");
  //   res.json({ msg: "promise worked!" });
  // });
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email already exists" });
      } else {
        const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
          s: "200", // Size
          r: "pg", // Rating
          d: "mm" // Default
        });

        const newUser = new User({
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          avatar,
          password: req.body.password
        });

        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser
              .save()
              .then(user => res.json(user))
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          });
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**models/User.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("Mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const users = require("./routes/api/users");
const profile = require("./routes/api/profile");
const posts = require("./routes/api/posts");

const app = express();

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to Mongo DB
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB Connected");
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));

// Use Routes
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/profile", profile);
app.use("/api/posts", posts);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: `user` won't be available to the debugger until line 20, what's its value there?

Comment: @JohnnyHK the debugger doesn't stop on line 20, maybe findOne() does not return a promise

Comment: yes,I'm getting MongoDB Connected in the console output.  Just tried using a callback instead of a promise as that seems to be what the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) says, although I'm surprised it's not a promise.  Either way it did not work.
Also tried to changing the version on all my dependencies to match the [tutorials](https://github.com/bradtraversy/devconnector/blob/master/package.json).  That also did not work :(

Comment: Guess I'm a bit confused. What's the actual server-side error?

Comment: What version of node.js is this running in?  The error about `user is not defined` makes me think you're running a version of node.js that does not understand arrow function syntax.

Comment: I typed `user` into the node console during debugging, and it gave that error.  If I don't type anything into the console during debugging no errors are shown.  I replaced the image in the post as I can see how that can be misleading. I'm using node v8.11.1

Comment: yeah, I can see from the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) that mongoose does have built in promises, for some reason they are not working though!

Comment: There is not server side error, but nothing returns from my ajax request on the frontend `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch` and I can see from debgging the issue that it's not going the then method

Comment: Your server must produce some error messages. Please, tell us what they say.

Comment: If it doesn't go into the `then` method it goes into the `catch` method. Since in this method you log the error, your server must log some message

Comment: I added the server console output to the question, I can't see anything useful in it.

Comment: It doesn't go into the catch method either, which is why I think `User.findOne()` is not returning a `Promise` but the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) says it does

Comment: Is it the console output after making the request?

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question with the console output on the frontend, I had it in the code block before.  Below is the terminal output from the server, nothing useful in it :(

I'm going to try connecting to a local mongoDB, and see if that helps somehow, in it's logs or something

Comment: In that case, your MongoDB instance is the problem. Try connecting to it using the mongodb cli and see what's going on

Comment: I don't think it's the DB as I see nothing in it's logs (I added the logs to the question), I don't think mongoose is connecting with it

Comment: Yes, @JognnyHK.  I'll try to simplify this down.  But won't have time today.  Than you everyone for your help and spending time on this

Comment: @JognnyHK I updated the questio to provide a more Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and also uploaded all the code to [github](https://github.com/Holly845/devconnector/) so that it can be reproduced.

Comment: not sure but if i remember you put undefined in the model export. try do const USER =  mongoose.model("users", UserSchema); and then in the next line export User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're requiring the Mongoose module using different names in server.js ("Mongoose") and models/User.js ("mongoose"). This creates separate instances of the module so the connection made by server.js isn't available to the `User` model and the `findOne` call is stuck waiting for a connection.

So just change that line in server.js to:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

Comment: Thanks a mil, that was it. It was driving me around the bend, haha, at least I learnt a few things trying to debug it! I would have thought there would only be one name you could use to require the same module, and it should throw an error subsequently if you use the wrong name. Ahh well, thanks again :)